# Problema con planteamiento SQL

Tags: sql

Estoy practicando para un examen en el que tengo que trabajar bajo este enunciado:
Crea una función denominada getPuntosEstrella. El objetivo de dicha
función es conocer los puntos que tiene un determinado cliente dependiendo del
número de pedidos realizados y en las fechas que lo ha realizado (rebajas, alta
temporada, etc).
• La función recibirá por parámetro el ID del USUARIO.
• Deberás obtener el número de pedidos realizados por el cliente teniendo en
cuenta las siguientes fechas:
◦ Enero, Febrero, Julio o Agosto cada pedido realizado sumará 5 puntos
◦ Marzo o Septiembre cada pedido realizado sumará 15 puntos.
◦ Abril u Octubre cada pedido realizado sumará 20 puntos.
◦ Junio, Noviembre y Diviembre cada pedido realizado sumará 30 puntos.```

Y este es mi código SQL:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION getPuntosEstrella (idUsuario INT)
RETURNS INT
BEGIN 
    DECLARE puntosEstrella INT;
    DECLARE esMes INT;
    DECLARE bonificacion INT;
    DECLARE total INT;

    SELECT COUNT(p.idUsuario) INTO puntosEstrella
    FROM pedidos p
    WHERE p.idUsuario = idUsuario;

    SELECT MONTH(p.fecha) INTO esMes
    FROM pedidos p 
    WHERE p.idUsuario = idUsuario;

    IF esMes IN (1,2,7,8) THEN
        SET bonificacion = 5;
        SET puntosEstrella = bonificacion + puntosEstrella;
    END IF;
    RETURN total;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

El error dice: Result consisted of more than one row

Llevo 40 minutos intentando solucionar el error que me da y no soy capaz, si alguien es capaz de ayudarme, lo agradecería.

Answer (score 0):

Suponiendo que tienes mas pedido que pertenecen a ese mes. Esto retorna más de una fila. Tu cláusula INTO está intentando escribir varias filas en una sola variable.

```
 SELECT MONTH(p.fecha) INTO esMes
    FROM pedidos p 
    WHERE p.idUsuario = idUsuario;
```

Edit: nuevo planteamiento

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION getPuntosEstrella (idUsuario INT)
RETURNS INT
BEGIN 
    DECLARE puntosEstrella INT;
    DECLARE total INT;
    DECLARE bonificacion5 INT;
    DECLARE bonificacion15 INT;
    DECLARE bonificacion20 INT;
    DECLARE bonificacion30 INT;

    SELECT COUNT(p.idUsuario) INTO puntosEstrella
    FROM pedidos p
    WHERE p.idUsuario = idUsuario;

    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO bonificacion5
    FROM pedidos p 
    WHERE p.idUsuario = idUsuario and MONTH(p.fecha) in (1,2,7,8);

    //PARA BONIFICACION 15
    ...
    //PARA BONIFICACION 20
    ...
    //PARA BONIFICACION 30
    ...

    SET total = puntosEstrella + bonificacion5*5 + bonificacion15*15 + bonificacion20*20 + bonificacion30*30;

    RETURN total;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Y cómo podría conseguir solucionarlo??

Comment: @Txni.26 tienes que replantear. O le pones condiciones al select para que dé un solo registro o cambias el tipo de la variable. Depende de lo que necesites.

Comment: @Txni.26 revisa el edit